# Rich Snippets only appear with "site:" search in Google

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

I am confused about the rich data results that Google displays.

I run an e-commerce store and am trying to get search results, that return products, to show pricing, stock, rating etc.

I have run searches via Google to return the same product and some results show this, some don't.

The below picture shows 2 searches run simultaneously, the top contains the rich data, the bottom does not:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've come across similar issue, Google will display rich snippets if they are correctly implemented using "site:" but they wont display it on normal results if they are not sure about the quality.

[John Muller discussed about this in his Office Hangouts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GEAc8MuxfY&feature=youtu.be&t=20m4s)

> Usually if you do a site: query for a site we will show the rich
>   snippets if its implemented technically correct so thats a good way to
>   kind of double check we can pick up the mark up properly and for not
>   showing it in normal search results then thats really a sign that we
>   are essentially not sure about the quality of the website

I can see you have only 1 review on your product that may be an indication for Google not to show the rich snippet.

I would advice you to try and get some more reviews. Also test products with more reviews to figure out if Google is not showing your rich snippet because of the site quality or because you dont have enough reviews.

The main takeaway here is that you have correctly implemented the rich snippets but Google is hesitating to show them because:

1. You need more reviews
2. You need to improve content/site quality

Try to increase your sites trust flow is one of the most important metrics when you are trying to win rich snippet positions.

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is a bit mixed up. It was hard to see what was going on in the Structured Data Testing Tool.

The Review is marked up as its own top level entity and references the products name. It should be part of the Product as the page is about a Product, that has reviews. So it's entity should be inside the Products entity.

The Product ends up being part of the breadcrumb list. This is because it shares the same id as the last breadcrumb item, so it gets merged in. Changing one of the ids will move it back to being a top level entity.

Fixing those errors may help Google trust it more and give you those real world rich snippets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you have any idea how to fix? I haven't done anything to it. This is the standard rich snippets from woocommerce

Comment: I'd suspect it is the theme that is not implementing it correctly. Maybe chart with the theme developer.